# Upgrade from 6.7.1 to 6.7.2 using docker container

Tags: curity

Currently, I am running Curity Identity server Community Edition version `6.7.1`  using docker container.

How do I upgrade it to Docker container to 6.7.2 as I have already configured all the settings and configurations as per `https://developer.curity.io/downloads`

```
docker run -it -e PASSWORD=<admin_user_password> -p 6749:6749 -p 8443:8443 curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr:6.7.2
```

Answer (score 3):

To upgrade to a new version, just export the current configuration via the admin UI and save the configuration file. Create then a Dockerfile that copies the configuration file to `$IDSVR_HOME/etc/init/` of the new container.

```
FROM curity.azurecr.io/curity/idsvr:6.7.2
COPY --chown=idsvr:root curity-config.xml /opt/idsvr/etc/init/
```

In case that you copied or manipulated any files (e.g. templates, plugins, drivers, log settings and more) of the current container, make sure to create a backup of those files and add copy statements in the Dockerfile for them.

Build a new image with the help of the Dockerfile and start the container from your custom image.

```
docker build Dockerfile-upgrade-idsvr custom-image
docker run -it -e PASSWORD=<admin_user_password> -p 6749:6749 -p 8443:8443 custom-image
```

For the next upgrade you only have to change the version of the idsvr image in the Dockerfile, rebuild the custom image and run the container again.

For more details on how to run Curity Identity Server with Docker, I recommend you to register for our [deployment course](https://curity.io/resources/webinars/course-deploying-curity-identity-server/) and/or [read this Docker tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/run-curity-docker/). Also, checkout the [general procedure](https://curity.io/docs/idsvr/latest/system-admin-guide/upgrade/index.html#general-upgrade-procedure) for upgrading.